# AngularJS - Filtering Data using checkbox and textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new in angularJS, I just want to filter my data using checkbox and textbox but I have no Idea how to do it. Please Help me.

Here is my data:

```
  $scope.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias', lname: 'TLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Jeff', lname: 'JLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Brian', lname: 'BLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Igor', lname: 'ILname', company: 'y'},
    {name: 'James', lname: 'JLname', company: 'z'},
    {name: 'Brad', lname: 'BLname', company: 'y'}
  ];
```

All I want is if I going to choose **x** from checkbox it will show the rows related with **Tobias** **Jeff** **Brian** and if I'm going to uncheck the checkbox and type **br**, **Brian** and **Brad** will show but if I'm going to check the x checkbox only **Bryan** should show. if I'm going to remove/erase the **br** and check both **x** and **y** all the related data should show. (Tobias, Jeff, Brian, Igor and Brad).

Respectfully Yours.

Comment: If you check multiple checkboxes it should act like `OR` condition or `AND`?

Comment: Looks like `or` for me, although build in filters can't filter by same key with multiple values - i mean something like `company: 'x', company: 'y'` you will need to write a custom filter for that

Comment: Can you share a plunker for this?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/18/

Comment: thank you very much for your response maurycy and dfsq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this could be done using a custom filter.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/27/

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>Search by Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filters.search"></div>
       <div>Show Company X: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="companyFilters.x"/></div>
       <div>Show Company Y: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="companyFilters.y"/></div>
       <div>Show Company Z: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="companyFilters.z"/></div>
       <div ng-repeat="arr in array | filter:filters.search | customFilter:companyFilters">
           <span ng-bind="arr.name"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.companyFilters = {
        x: false,
        y: false,
        z: false
    };

    $scope.filters = {
        search: ''
    };

    $scope.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias', lname: 'TLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Jeff', lname: 'JLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Brian', lname: 'BLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Igor', lname: 'ILname', company: 'y'},
    {name: 'James', lname: 'JLname', company: 'z'},
    {name: 'Brad', lname: 'BLname', company: 'y'}
  ];
})
.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(input, companies) {

      console.log(input);
      consoloe.log(companies);
      var filteredList = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i ++) {
          for(var c = 0; c < companies.length; c ++) {
              console.log(input[i].company);
              console.log(companies[i]);
              if(input[i].company === companies[c]) {
                  filteredList.push(input[i]);
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      console.log(filteredList);
      return filteredList;
  };
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, just add an if condition that returns the input if everything is false.  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/32/

Comment: Hi link13, I was wondering if it is possible to count all the data was displayed base on the company. example is when check x and y, the label for x is equal to 3 and y is equal to 2, however when I type **br** in the text box the label for x will be 1 and y will also be 1. please be patient to me, I was very new with this platform and I'm starting to love it because of it is very good tool in development. Respectfully Your.

Comment: Sure just add a filter on the controller and count.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/34/

Comment: I love it!, thank you very much for your help. may I know what **input** and **companies** on the filter? I'm so confuse what is the inside of those and how the program fill those. this filter was so amazing.. I want to learn more deep on it.

Comment: those are populated through the markup with this: 'customFilter:companyFilters', input is the dataset that ng-repeat is iterating through, and companies is 'companyFilters' which is passed through the markup

Comment: oh I see. thank you very much for your help Link13, you are awesome!. and thank you also to stack overflow for this kind of service. I really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Hi Link13, I just want to ask again if I'm going to add 2 checkboxes which filter other field. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/38/

Comment: Example: if I'm going to check the contractual employee it will show are **igor** and **james** and at the same time it will update the counter, and if I check the company **y** it will show only **igor** also update those counter. please help me again Link13. I've Tried to do it but i think my knowledge wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom filter function. Check it out.

```
$scope.filterUsers = function (user) {

    var result = true,
        filters = $scope.filterBy,
        condition = $scope.filter;

    for (key in filters) {
        if (filters[key]) {
            if (user[key].indexOf(condition) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Usage:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in array | filter:filterUsers">{{user.name}} {{user.lname}},   {{user.company}}</li>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/oqe5ADcE1t3OOoePE1oK?p=preview

Comment: Hello dfsq, thanks for your answer, however what I want is filter the record from the checkbox: ie. if I check **x** and **y** all company has **x** and **y** will be show and if I key in on the textbox it will filter those result from **x** and **y** based on the value of the textbox.